# how to pass the dynamic variable in raw sql query using django mysql

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How to archive the following...

i need to pass two variable date which comes as long format and apply this variable in a subquery using raw sql django

```
def duplicatephoneno(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(payload)
    if payload:
        startdate=payload['from']
        enddate=payload['to']
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(MYSQLdb.escape_string("SELECT * FROM `allergy` WHERE `allergy`.`patient_n_key` IN (SELECT `patient_masters`.`patient_n_key` FROM `patient_masters` WHERE `patient_masters`.`created_on`between %s AND %s)",[startdate], [enddate]))
            row = dictfetchall(cursor)
            patientuser=serializers.serialize('json', row)
        return HttpResponse(patientuser, content_type='application/json;charset=utf8')
```

Comment: So `startdate` and `enddate` are strings? Can you give an example of the format?

Comment: Tq Mr will keeling.Yes I need to give string only Ex.Varchar field.where am i going wrong.

Comment: Hi Mr pandelis i have run the above code which you edited but I am getting error MysqlDB is not defined but i have imported in my local but again i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

## Try  this

```
def duplicatephoneno(request):
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(payload)

    if payload:
        startdate=payload['from']
        enddate=payload['to']
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:

            queries="SELECT * FROM `allergy` WHERE `allergy`.`patient_n_key` IN (SELECT `patient_masters`.`patient_n_key` FROM `patient_masters` WHERE `patient_masters`.`created_on`between %s AND %s)"
            data_tuple=(startdate,enddate)
            cursor.execute(queries,data_tuple)
            connection.commit()
            row = cursor.fetchall()
            patientuser=serializers.serialize('json', row)
            return HttpResponse(patientuser, content_type='application/json;charset=utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs mention how to do this.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) Note you will not be able to use this method if you are using an SQLite database.

As a side note, using raw queries should be your last resort. The Django ORM is pretty good these days and you should really only use raw queries if there is a type of query that is unsupported by the ORM (rare) or the ORM generated querystring has a significant performance cost compared to your custom raw query. Querysets (the objects returned by ORM queries) are also pretty easy to turn into JSON like you seem to be doing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicatephoneno(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    payload = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(payload)
    if payload:
        startdate=payload['from']
        enddate=payload['to']
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(MYSQLdb.escape_string("SELECT * FROM `allergy` WHERE `allergy`.`patient_n_key` IN (SELECT `patient_masters`.`patient_n_key` FROM `patient_masters` WHERE `patient_masters`.`created_on`between %s AND %s)",[startdate, enddate]))
            row = dictfetchall(cursor)
            patientuser=serializers.serialize('json', row)
        return HttpResponse(patientuser, content_type='application/json;charset=utf8')
```